# Splitting a text line into separate lines from command line

Tags: text, split, command

What are some simple options to split a single text line into separate based on a character or pattern? I would like to do this from the command line.

An example would be when you want to inspect the PATH. With a single simple command I'd like to split something like:

```
    /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/jeff/bin:/Users/jeff/Utveckling/Alan/alan/bin:/Users/jeff/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/bin
```

into the much more readable

```
/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/texbin
/Users/jeff/bin
/Users/jeff/Utveckling/Alan/alan/bin
/Users/jeff/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/jeff/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: What OS/command language is this for?  You need to indicate this somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **tr** actually was easier, as show in e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) question. Here's the command

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
sed s/:/\\n/g yourinput
```

should do the trick